# re.sub combine two rules in one sub

Tags: python

I have a bunch of sentences that either start with "This color is red" or "This color is pink".

I'd like to create an `re.sub()` rule to combine the removal of both, and keep "rest of sentence." How can I combine these two sub rules into one? :

```
a = "This color is red rest of sentence"
b = "This color is pink rest of sentence"

re.sub('This.+ red','', a)
re.sub('This.+ pink','', b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `|` as an `OR` operation in regex:

```
print(re.sub('This.+ (red|pink)', '', a))
# rest of sentence
print(re.sub('This.+ (red|pink)', '', b))
# rest of sentence
```

Comment: Is there a way to combine rules so that different replacements are given for "red" and "pink? Ex. so red is replaced with "orange" and pink with "purple"?

Comment: Don't think thats possible using only one `re.sub`